# Unable to connect to Jira by basic authentication

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I tried to connect to Jira by  basic authentication as discussed [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Example+-+Basic+Authentication), but had 401 error.

Here password and login are the same `c27115@trbvm.com`

My curl

```
curl -D- -u c27115@trbvm.com:c27115@trbvm.com -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/project

curl -D- -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic YzI3MTE1QHRyYnZtLmNvbTpjMjcxMTVAdHJidm0uY29t" -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/project"
```

Here the response [result](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j1h8ywkglufllqc/response?dl=0).

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, username.":".password);
```

This shoud do it.

Comment: I just use curl utility without php.

Comment: the second one after basic the string i assume is the base 64 encoded variant of the userpass combination?
 "c27115@trbvm.com:c27115@trbvm.com" string

Comment: can you update the issue with the response you get from curl?Thanks.

Comment: can you send the response from both requests? the first one is with success?